# C# Excel InterOp: Deleting All Rows Below Row 2

Tags: c#, excel, interop, rows

This should not be hard but so far every solution I have found is not working. Basically, I am populating an Excel Sheet starting with Row 3 using a C# console application. The population part works but what I need to do is to delete all rows with their data starting with row 3. And here is my code so far:

```
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;                 
for (int j = 3; j <= xlRange.Rows.Count; j++)
{
   ///  xlRange.Rows[j].EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
        xlRange.Rows[j].Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
 }
```

Note, both commented out code and the functional code generate something like Delete function cannot be reached.

Thanks!

***Update 1*** It looks like the following does work in the loop on another Excel file; so there is some kind of lock on the other Excel file.

```
  ((Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Rows[j]).Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
```

***Update 2***

So, yes, strangely the original XLS file is password protected and I don't have password yet. The file allows me to write new values and over-write existing values doesn't allow me to delete rows!!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me fine but not on the needed file because of the password protection on that file, as indicated in my 'updates' to the Question. There are macros in the needed file and so I can't simply use work-arounds like upload to Google Docs etc.

HTH

```
 ((Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Rows[j]).Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
```